# Why can a program, which writes to a file, keep running without any error even if the file has been deleted

Tags: linux, file, logging, file-descriptor

I'm using Linux for a while and today I found an interesting thing.

Saying that I have an infinite program, which keeps writing strings into a file.

If I delete the file while running the program, I thought some error would generate by the program. To my surprise, nothing happened...

Here is how I create the ininite program with c++11:

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream outputFile("./target");
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        outputFile << i << endl;
        i++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So after running it, I get a new file name `target`. If I delete this file (`rm ./target`), no error will be generated.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't any error generated?
2. If the file has been deleted, where are those strings written?
3. Is it possible to recreate a new file to be written without restarting the infinite program?

Comment: AFAIR the OS has no idea the file is removed (i.e. no filesystem watcher is set), still the file descriptor is there. Also, if you want to recreate a new file everytime it disappears you can have a look at [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)

Comment: @peyo So what does `rm ./target` delete?

Comment: `rm ./target` removes the inode information about the file you're deleting. Basically, the address of the file's chunks on the drive. Thant's why the man writes `Remove (unlink) the FILE(s).` This is the reason undelete tools like photorec can find your file after deletion as long as you don't overwrite it. (cf. what user414777 explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 1 & 2: When you believe you have deleted the file, what you actually have done is that you have deleted the "link" to the file. Since your program  is already running, the file is actually open. The file is still there and can be written to and read from if you have access to it. So, no error message since you are still writing to the file.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't read it through any linux command such as `cat` because I have `rm` it but the file still exists?

Comment: @Yves On Linux, you can still access it even if deleted through `cat /proc/<pid>/fd/3` (`3` most probably, could be `4` or something else).

Comment: @user414777 So does it mean that the kernel will hold the whole file in RAM so that the file, which has been `rm`, can still be writable by the process which opened it?

Comment: @Yves it doesn't hold it "in RAM", unless the file is located on some RAM-based filesystem like tmpfs. When the open file description refers to an on-disk inode, the kernel could completely swap any buffered parts of the file to its on-disk inode.